# Meteor: Synchronous method

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm failing to run a method on the server side synchronously, meaning to wait for it to be done.

```
mymethod: function(par1, par2){

  var timer = Meteor.setTimeout(function() {

      //do something       

  });
}
```

I tried to use Meteor.wrapAsync without success, whether I wrap the timer or the entire method like this:

```
Meteor.wrapAsync(Meteor.call('mymethod', par1, par2));
```

Comment: I suggest to use `npm` package , look at here https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm#async-utilities

Comment: wrapping the timer should work. can you show the code you used for that?

Answer (score 0):

Weird.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    mymethod: function(par1, par2) {
      var timer = Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
          console.log("Hey!");
      }, 1000);
    }
  });

  Meteor.call('mymethod', 'par1', 'par2');
}
```

works fine here in a newly created 0.9.3.1 app.

Comment: Yea, but I think that if you use `Meteor.userId()` in your delayed function, it may not contain the id for the user calling the method.